# Append something to wordpress nav menu using wp_nav_menu_objects

Tags: wordpress

I want to append something to a wordpress navigation menu. My code here works, however, right now it puts my content inside the "a" tag of each item. I want it OUTSIDE of the "a" tag - right before the closing "li" tag of each item.

*I have searched high and low but the wordpress documentation is limited regarding this...*

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);
function my_wp_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'main-menu' ) {
        // loop
        foreach( $items as &$item ) {
            
            // vars
            $mytext = "content";

            // append
            if( $mytext ) {
                $item->title .= $mytext;
            }
        }
    }
    // return
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: This filter filters the actual link element. If you want to add content to the `li`, you might need to use the filter in the nav walker: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/ - `apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );` - if you look at line 231 in the walker, you can see where you can add your content.

Comment: Thanx, I figured it out! Thank you soooooo much for your help!!!!!!